# How to enter Ubuntu after installing Ubuntu alongside Windows10?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I followed the instructions to install Ubuntu 16.04 alongside my windows 10 PC.

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNeJvujdB-0

After I finished installation and restarted the computer, it still brings me back to previous page.

[image: Ubuntu instalation first menu page]

Comment: did you remove the install media?

Comment: @ravery If i remove the install media, it brings me back to windows10

Comment: then you didn't install grub correctly. were you in EFI mode when you installed ubuntu? did you use the amd64 installer?

Comment: But I need to enter ubuntu first in order to install grub, right?

Comment: if you weren't in EFI mode you have to reinstall ubuntu

Comment: I'm in EFI mode. I didn't use the amd64 installer.

Comment: then you did not install in EFI mode. get the amd64 installer and reinstall